# How to create a canvas with a circle inside it everytime a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I am stuck with a code and my job is to keep on adding canvas when button is clicked. this canvas should also hold a circle. Whenever a button is clicked it should result in displaying a new canvas with a circle inside beside older ones(canvas that are created earlier). Please Help.
This is my code
The two canvases created are default on page and new ones should be created upon clicking the button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas1" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillText("Alex", 10, 50);

var d = document.getElementById("myCanvas1");
var ctx1 = d.getContext("2d");
ctx1.beginPath();
ctx1.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx1.stroke();
ctx1.fillText("Clay", 10, 50);
</script>

<script>

function fun(){
var e = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx2 = e.getContext("2d");
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx2.stroke();
window.alert();
}
</script>

<br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="fun()">+</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please share your code so we can look at what you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so what I did was I took part of your code(for the circle), and did what you asked!
in this JsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jrhvcrtm/), When you click the button, you get a new div, with the same properties as the other one, with a circle inside.

Just use this in your own code, and if you didn't realize yet, it uses jQuery in it.
Here is a snippet:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

$('#button').click(function() {
     var el = $("#test"),  
     newone = el.clone(true);
     el.before(newone);//This line is added just for styling
});

$('#button').click(function() {
var e = document.getElementById("test");
var ctx2 = e.getContext("2d");
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx2.stroke();
window.alert();
});
```

```css
#test {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#button {
 height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="button">
Click
</button>
<canvas id="test" class="test"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank You so much:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var e = document.getElementById("myCanvas2")`, create a new canvas, then append it to your `body`.

```
var e = document.createElement('canvas') // create new canvas
document.body.appendChild(e) // make it accessible on the DOM

var ctx2 = e.getContext("2d")
// remain the same code ...
```

You may also put all canvas in a `<div id="canvases"></div>` for a better management. Then the onclick listener will be as following code.

```
var e = document.createElement('canvas')
var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvases')
document.body.appendChild(canvasContainer)

var ctx2 = e.getContext("2d")
// remain the same code ...
```